# Fallback font-family for each google font?

Tags: css, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm looking for a fallback font family for each google font.  The context for this is that I have created a CSS utility module containing [all google fonts](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-utilities-fonts/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css).  The font utilities are produced approximately like this:

```
@each $font in 'Open Sans', Montserrat, Roboto, Lato, ... {

   .u-font-$(font) {
      font-family: var(--font-$(font)) !important;
    }
}
```

I'd like to also include a custom fallback family for each font.  Does anyone know if there's a way to obtain a font family that is a good browser fallback for each font?  The below is approximately what I'd like to do:

```
        .u-font-$(font) {
          font-family: "$(font)", var(--$(font)-fallback-family) !important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for the closest system font for each Google font?

Comment: Yes - and ideally it would be keyed like this (Example) --open-sans-fallback-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; I have more examples here - This is the repository the fallback fonts would go in https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-variables-fonts/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this? I find it weird that Google doesn't include this in their API responses.

Comment: I noticed that Google Workbox can cache the fonts when it builds a PWA, so one way to ensure that the font's are there is to build a PWA site ....

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I don't find a complete list, but find an great tools: [font-style-matcher](https://meowni.ca/font-style-matcher/) and also a [good article](https://dev.to/masakudamatsu/which-fallback-fonts-should-we-choose-to-make-fout-less-jarring-3d8d) about font fallback